# Ruby Mash equivalent in Python?

Tags: python, ruby, mocking

in Ruby, there's this awesome library called a [Mash](http://intridea.com/2008/4/12/mash-mocking-hash-for-total-poser-objects?blog=company) which is a Hash but through clever use of missing_method can convert:

```
object['property']
```

to

```
object.property
```

This is really useful for mocks. Anyone know of a similar kind of thing in Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it absolutely necessary that you base this on a dict?  Python objects can dynamically acquire attributes with very little extra plumbing:

```
>>> class C(object): pass
...
>>> z = C()
>>> z.blah = "xyzzy"
>>> dir(z)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', ... '__weakref__', 'blah']
```

Comment: Wow that's great thanks! I'd love to give extra points for such a fast answer too :)

Answer (score 4):

Is `__getitem__` what you're looking for?

```
class C:
   def __init__(self):
      self.my_property = "Hello"

   def __getitem__(self, name):
      return getattr(self, name)

c = C()
print c['my_property']  # Prints "Hello"
```

or are you looking for the reverse of that, via`__getattr__`?

```
class D(dict):
   def __getattr__(self, name):
      return self[name]

d = D()
d['x'] = "Hello"
print d.x  # Prints "Hello"
```

(**Edit**: As Paul McGuire kindly points out in the comments, this code only demonstrates the bare bones of a full solution.)

Comment: For more complete attribute emulation, also implement `__dir__` to return all dict's attributes, plus all user-specified names.

Comment: Will conflict with dict's own attributes, like items, values, etc. since `__getattr__` will only get called if no attribute is found.  So d['items'] can be set, but can never be retrieved by this `__getattr__`.  To work around this, write D to contain and delegate to a dict, rather than inherit from dict.

Comment: Lastly, the OP is trying to write mocks, so `__setattr__` is probably going to come into the picture at some point, so that `x.xyzzy` can be written as well as read.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it absolutely necessary that you base this on a dict?

Yes if you then want to treat it as a list of items, without abusing `__dict__`.

The following is my old answer to the Mash question. It provides a default, the default may be a method or an object, if it's an object it will clone deeply (*not* just hot-link) if it's used more than once.

And it exposes its simple key values as `.key`:

```
def Map(*args, **kwargs):
    value = kwargs.get('_default', None)
    if kwargs.has_key('_default'):  del kwargs['_default']

 # CONSIDER  You may want to look at the collections.defaultdict class.
 #      It takes in a factory function for default values.
 #
 # You can also implement your class by overriding the __missing__ method
 #      of the dict class, rather than overriding the __getitem__.
 #
 # Both were added in Python 2.5 according to the documentation.

    class _DefMap(dict):
        'But CONSIDER http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bunch/1.0.0 '

        def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
            dict.__init__(self, *a, **kw)
            self.__dict__ = self

        def __getitem__(self, key):

            if not self.has_key(key):

                if hasattr(value, '__call__'):
                    self[key] = value(key)
                else:
                    self[key] = copy.deepcopy(value)

            return dict.__getitem__(self, key)

    return _DefMap(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mash . Also you can convert dict to mash object.